# c++ simpleini example on getting a ini file from a directory?

Tags: c++, file, ini

hi could someone help me i'm trying getting the liberty simpleini for c++ to read/write a file from a different directory but so far nothing is working.

using windows 7

```
#include "SimpleIni.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
CSimpleIniA ini;

ini.SetValue("test", "default", "1");
ini.SaveFile("c:\\test\\test.ini");
//tried ini.SaveFile("c:\test\test.ini");

ini.LoadFile("c:\\test\\test.ini");
//tried ini.LoadFile("c:\test\test.ini");
const char * set = ini.GetValue("test", "default", "");

printf( "value = %s", set ); // should load from c:\test\test.ini

return 0;
}
```

source http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini-doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in that it doesn't create directories.
You should create "c:\test" directory first on your own and then start application.
I started with your code and it didn't work, then I created "test" folder on drive C and it began to.